# Time Picker makes my App crash with Error: E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am sorry that I need your help again. I really try to solve all this stuff myself but because I only make Android Coding since this year, I am still from time to time overwhelmed.

I tried to do a Time Picker. If I do it in a new Project, it works perfectly. But as soon as I put it into my "original App", the App runs until View 3, where I have the Time Picker. I also can open the Time Picker. I pick the time, but as soon as I click on ok, it says: Unfortunately, App has stopped. With a click on ok I jump back on View 2. I already tried to reorganize the Code and deleted the Emulator and made a new One. Doesn't matter what I do, it is not working. Can it be possible, that I just still have the wrong order in the Class because I try to add different Attributes to the App I learned independently from each other?

I think the TimePickerFragment should be right cause the picker works but here I add it again:

```
 public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

I added the time picker in the class below

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD).format(calendar.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());

        TextView textViewDate = findViewById(R.id.Date);
        textViewDate.setText(currentDate);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.Time2);
        textView.setText(time);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Time1);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                  timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
              }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
        textView.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main class just do that as it's an activity not fragment[image: it's a picture from my repo, it would enlightened you]

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DATE_FIELD).format(calendar.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());

    TextView textViewDate = findViewById(R.id.Date);
    textViewDate.setText(currentDate);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.Time2);
    textView.setText(time);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Time1);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
              timePicker.show();
          }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    textView.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
}
 }
```

Comment: instead of all the code I wrote for it or on a certain position? would be so much faster. I did sooo much code in there lol

Comment: just instead of that : timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");

Comment: I tried. Thats the result: 

timePicker.show();
                            ^
    method DialogFragment.show(FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable

Comment: remove this : timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker"); and put this  timePicker.show();

Comment: ok obviously I am not allowed to put the whole code in again. sorry for that. but O thought i exactly did it there:

         @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
              timePicker.show();
          }

Comment: ok. I recoded it all. I am sorry to ask again but it wont work doesnt matter what i do. If i do the show() it says there has to be something in the brackets. show this part below again. Sorry that I need so much help.

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TimeStart);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                  timePicker.show();
              }
        });
    }

Comment: I updated my answer as you sound to have a misunderstanding

Comment: i am really really sorry. I feel really embarrassed but i dont see where the mistake is sitting now. i deleted the whole line you told me and put. timePicker.show(); in. lol sorry i am a lil desperate and overwhelmed. I am so sorry

Comment: You should not , we are all here to learn. So, feel free to ask to learn. Just try it and let me know what happened with you

Comment: you dont do anything in () right? I obviously do it wrong. It still wants something in the brackets of show()

Comment: I edited my answer again and attached a picture to make things more clear

Comment: do i only add the line in your picture with the timePickerDialog? I compared the code under the picture and tried it with copy and paste and both changed it. so i try it with your picture

Comment: lol no. I would show you my code again to figure out what i do wrong. I am too blind to see it lol just kidding. but last time i put an answer in here myself to show whole code again it got deleted. there's no way to show it again is there?